# What to use for rendering deformable object in opengl?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I want to render heightmap that are able to deform using latest opengl. What method is recommended for rendering in opengl? Some acceleration method requires that the vertices to be static in order to be stored in high speed memory(gpu mem).

I need a techniques that can exploit gpu features since im rendering huge number of vertices for the heightmap. Before anyone tells me to use LOD, im using LOD already. I want to optimize it.

Comment: opengl or opengles? deform via user input (like mouse) or only some procedural animation?

Comment: Im planning to use monogame, portable class library for cross platform. Intially development will start targeting windows platform. Then i would like to expand the development to mobile platform(android, ios, windows phone). As for deformation, the heightmap mesh is deform for lod transition and probably algorithm for crack fixing/morphing. with lod, the mesh data needs to be updated regularly depending on the user viewport and distance. i hope people understand what i said.

Comment: If your deployment device/OS profile supports it (all iOS 7 devices can, but I dunno about other platforms), I'd recommend looking into vertex texture fetch. Keep your vertex data static -- just a highly tessellated plane. Write your height map to a texture, then sample that texture in the vertex shader and adjust the output vertex position accordingly.